# Could not find or load main class org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen (kettle and geokettle)

Tags: kettle, geokettle

First of all, I am not an IT person and therefore my doubts must seem "strange"

I have installed on my machine the Kettle and Geokettle in different drives.
I intend to run scripts (.bat) to execute Jobs using the Kitchen, either in the Kettle and GeoKettle

I have the following settings:

```
System Variables: Kettle_Home = C:/Qgis_install
Kitchen in Kettle: C:\QGIS_Install\data-integration\Kitchen.bat
Kitchen in GeoKettle: D:\Program Files\GeoKettle\Kitchen.bat
```

With that I can run nicely, for example, this "Kettle script" on my machine:

```
../../data-integration/kitchen.bat /file="../geoairc/etl/spo/01load.kjb"
```

I need to run a Geokettle script and I tried this way:

```
"D:/Program Files/GeoKettle/kitchen.bat" /file="C:/QGIS_Install/geoairc/etl/02load_shape.kjb"
```

whith that I get the error:*Could not find or load main class org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen*

As anyone know what should I do to be able to run also the "geokettle script" ?
Hope I have been able to make myself understood ...

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Comment: I have no experience with GeoKettle, but your kettle_home points to the "normal" kettle installation directory. Maybe GeoKettle uses kettle_home as well and can't find its libraries there. I'd have a look at the GeoKettle kitchen.bat and set kettle_home to the GeoKettle install dir in that bat file.

Comment: Dirk,
Thanks for the insight.

I changed the kettle_home to the GeoKettle dir (also in the bat file I'm want to run declare the kettle_home=GeoKettle dir) and have the same error...

Comment: both versions of Kettle work with the java version you have installed?

Comment: Yes, I can run transformations and jobs in Ketlle en GeoKettle with no problem